# Updating a specific field within a JSONB column in Supabase in Flutter

Tags: flutter, jsonb, supabase

In my Flutter Web Application that uses Supabase, in the database there is a Respondent table with a `logs` field that is of type `jsonb`. In this logs field, it will be a fixed list with the following format `{ "created_at" : timestamp, "last_login" : timestamp, "profile_update" : timestamp }`.

Using plain SQL statement, I have successfully inserted an entry in the logs field with these VALUES  `jsonb_build_object('created_at', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'last_login', NULL, 'profile_update', NULL)`

However, I need to update the `last_login` field only.  There is this [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/Supabase/comments/18bof7y/updating_one_variable_on_jsonb_from_flutter/#:%7E:text=To%20update%20a%20specific%20field,object%2C%20losing%20the%20city%20field.) that uses **.raw**. As mentioned from the example:

```
await Supabase.instance.client
    .from('your_table_name') // Replace with your actual table name
    .update({
      'address': Supabase.instance.client.raw('jsonb_set(address, \'{country}\', \'"the Netherlands"\')')
    })
    .match({'address->country': 'NL'})
    .execute();
```

However when I tried this approach, it cannot be debugged/run since there is no .raw() function.

I tried this one below, there was no error but nothing happens. But I am sure this function was invoked because it displayed the "Update here", but there was no response printed out.

```
Future<void> updateLastLogin(String id) async {
    try {
      print('Update here');
      final response = await supabase.from('respondents').update({
        'logs': {'last_login': DateTime.now()}
      }).eq('id', id);
      print(response);
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception(error);
    }
  }
```

How can I update a specific field in jsonb? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the Reddit post that uses `.raw()` function to solve your problem is just generated from ChatGPT as we have never had a `raw()` function or anything similar, and it also uses a `.execute()` function that has been removed from the SDK a long time ago.

If you know that your users will have the `created_at`, `last_login`, and `profile_update` fields, why not just create three different columns? It will solve all the issues that you have. It's always better to create columns if you have uniform data.